# how to update or insert the records in the sugarcrm after the marketing crms target status changed?

Tags: sugarcrm

how can i update or insert the records in the sales crm after the marketing crms target  status changed . i tried by exporting all the marketing targets having particular status and imported into sales. But i want to do this automatically .  i have two servers for each sales sugarcrm and marketing sugarcrm,so i want to know how to sync data between two severs conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding over your explanation ....

you can call webservice conditionally in after_save logic hook which will save/update record in another instance of Sugar.
sugar wsdl url : http://sugar_dev_URL.com/service/v2_1/soap.php?wsdl